# When must I overload operator <<?

Tags: c++, object

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct X{
    int _x;
    X(int x=0):_x(x){}
};

int main() {
    X arr[5];
    for (int i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    for (int i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
        cout << arr[i] <<",";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When must I overload `operator <<`?

I think since `arr` has ints so I shouldn't overload `<<`?

Comment: `arr` is an array of `X`, not of `int`. That's why you have to overload `operator<<` for streams, because there is no existing overload of that operator that takes an `X`.

Comment: *When must I overload operator whatever?* When the compiler tells you it cannot find a suitable overload (you try use it and get a compiler error).

Comment: try `std::cout << arr[i]._x;`. You dont have to overload anything to make it work, but `_x` looks like it is supposed to be private, so having an appropriate overload would be nicer

Comment: wow thanks !! @Rakete1111

Comment: then why I shoudl'nt overload operator []? @Rakete1111

Comment: @AssiaKhteb Because `arr` is an array. It is not `X`. It has type `X[5]`, so it has the default semantics of arrays, decay to pointer, `operator[]`, ... If you made a custom class `Y` that is basically an array, and then do `Y<X> array; array[0] = 4;`, if `Y` doesn't have an `operator[]`, it won't compile, because it isn't a "standard" array.

Comment: thanks <3 @Rakete1111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your `X` is just a wrapper around a singular `int` property it is a different type than `int`. The good news is you can just delegate to the `int` method by adding this function:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const X& x) {
  o << x._x;
  return o;
}
```

Comment: `operator<<` that writes to an `ostream` must be implemented as a standalone function, not as a member of the struct. And `friend` is not needed since `_x` is publicly accessible.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Just threw this together quickly and it did compile successfully and run as expected. I've taken your advice into account with an edit.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `operator<<` can very well be defined in a struct/class. I never had problems with it, and as far as I know, it is perfectly legal to do so too. Why not?

Comment: @Rakete1111 I've always done it as a `friend operator` inside classes (to access private/protected data) without any problems, but I've also seen it frequently implemented as a stand-alone function. Is there a best practice here?

Comment: @tadman None that I know of. If you define it inside the class, it's implicitly `inline` and can only be found using ADL. If you define it outside, then not. It really depends on your use case, there is much of a difference there IMO.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Good point about inline, but yeah, otherwise I can't see a problem here. Out of an abundance of caution I've gone with the stand-alone function approach because C++ can have some crazy edge cases.